# Question in solving errors in C++ in Visual Studio2022

Tags: c++, database, visual-studio, data-structures

How to solve the following errors in this code in visual studio 2022 version:                                                         expected an identifier on line 33
identifier "otherUser" is undefined on line 33                                                                 expected a']' on line 33                                                                                 identifier "ratings" is undefined on line 38                                                               language feature 'structured bindings' requires compiler flag 'std:c++17' on line 33

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

#include <xlnt/xlnt.hpp>

// Define a type alias for a map that maps a user ID to a vector of ratings
using UserRatings = std::map<int, std::vector<double>>;

// Define a function to calculate the cosine similarity between two users
double cosineSimilarity(const std::vector<double>& user1, const std::vector<double>& user2) {
    // Initialize variables to store the dot product and the magnitudes of the vectors
    double dotProduct = 0.0;
    double magnitude1 = 0.0;
    double magnitude2 = 0.0;
    // Calculate the dot product and magnitudes of the vectors
    for (size_t i = 0; i < user1.size(); i++) {
        dotProduct += user1[i] * user2[i];
        magnitude1 += user1[i] * user1[i];
        magnitude2 += user2[i] * user2[i];
    }

    // Calculate and return the cosine similarity
    return dotProduct / (sqrt(magnitude1) * sqrt(magnitude2));
}
// Define a function to predict the rating of a movie for a given user
double predictRating(const UserRatings& userRatings, int user, int movie) {
    // Initialize variables to store the predicted rating and the sum of the similarities
    double prediction = 0.0;
    double sumSimilarities = 0.0;
    // Iterate over all users in the userRatings map
    for (const auto& [otherUser, ratings] : userRatings) {
        // Skip the current user
        if (otherUser == user) continue;

        // Calculate the similarity between the current user and the other user
        double similarity = cosineSimilarity(userRatings.at(user), ratings);

        // If the similarity is positive, add it to the sum of similarities and
        // add the other user's rating for the movie to the prediction
        if (similarity > 0) {
            sumSimilarities += similarity;
            prediction += similarity * ratings[movie];
        }
    }

    // Return the predicted rating for the movie
    return prediction / sumSimilarities;
}
int main() {
    // Load the data from an Excel file
    xlnt::workbook workbook;
    workbook.load("ratings.xlsx");
    xlnt::worksheet sheet = workbook.active_sheet();
    // Create a map of user ratings
    UserRatings userRatings;
    for (auto row : sheet.rows()) {
        int user = row[0].value<int>();
        std::vector<double> ratings;
        for (auto cell : row) {
            if (cell.column() == 1) continue;
            ratings.push_back(cell.value<double>());
        }
        userRatings[user] = ratings;
    }
    // Predict the rating of movie 3 for user 1
    double prediction = predictRating(userRatings, 1, 3);
    std::cout << "Predicted rating for movie 3 by user 1: " << prediction << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I want to implement dataset from an excel file

Comment: What C++ standard is your project set to?

Comment: _"...requires compiler flag 'std:c++17' ..."_

Comment: Select Project->Properties from the menu. In the dialog box there is a choice "C++ Language Standard" - don't select the default value there, as this apparently doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code we could see that the code lacks the definition of the following variables, you need to define them according to your requirements.

[image]

> feature 'structured bindings' requires compiler flag 'std:c++17' on
> line 33

For this error, you need to right click on the project and select project properties, then set C++ Language Standard to c++17.

[image]